# find the website address which load my website in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I generate an script and get it to my clients to put it in their website

```
<script src="www.mysite.com/getframe.php?siteid=hash"></script>
```

(hash is unique for each website)
In getcode.php I return this text

```
document.write('<iframe src="www.mysite.com/showads.php"></iframe>');
```

Now for security I need to know which website put my script and compare it's url with the hash code to see if some one use another website hash in his website

Comment: Inspect `$_SERVER` ... what you want is in there

Comment: @charlietfl no it get mysite parametrs not the parent website

Comment: Use $_SERVER to see where request comes from and compare to your stored data for `siiteId`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$_SERVER`'s *http_referer* property:

```
$httpReferer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null;
```

Or your answer is inside `HTTP_HOST` or `REMOTE_HOST`.
Try `var_dump($_SERVER)` and see for yourself.

Comment: I tried this way but because iframe load mysite.com url , all parametrs in $_SERVER related to mysite.com And HTTP_REFERER is null , also there is several way to change HTTP_REFERER so i need more secure solution

Comment: Should you not check this inside `getframe.php`? Have you tested it there? Don't you get there the information you need?!